Early 80s story about unethical private doctor of rich old woman
In the early 1980s there was a magazine short story, probably in Asimov's or Analog where a private doctor and the rich old woman he works for try unethical, because untested, treatments on her, ignoring the risks that those treatments were not proved safe or effective, and eventually their luck runs out.
And what I remember most about the story was the doctor's impression when he first met his client, seeing her as a withered old hag on death's door, thus explaining her desperation and desire to try unproven therapies.  The story made it seem like she was as close to death as Jeanne Calment (1875-1997) was a decade later. And her age was described as being in her early 80s.
And I was sort of amused by the contrast between how old a woman in her eighties was depicted in the story and how vigorous my two grandmothers were at a similar age when I read the story.

I assume the treatments hit the level of fantasy/sci-fi?

Is there nothing else you can tell us about the story? What went wrong and what was the outcome? Something nightmarish?

A very weak match would be Cyril Kornbluth's The Little Black Bag. Unlikely to be the answer, though.

The date doesn't quite match, but Charles Sheffield's 1990 novelette "Health Care System" is about an unethical doctor who helps a wealthy old woman obtain better health care - by (among other things) arranging brain surgery to be performed on other doctors (and other care-givers), making them utterly devoted to the woman's care.  It doesn't work out as well as hoped.
This brief review says:

(H)ere a variety of medical technologies from organ transplants, medical
databases, and new drugs to sinister mind control implants – but ends
up horribly oppressive. Granted, this is a technology perverted by
Miriam Greenwood and not robots, and she preys on Thomas Matlock’s
obsession with money and women to support her obsession with life
extension. Justifiable motives – sex, money, and life – here lead to
thorough moral and physical corruption.

The story is available online here and there are frequent references to the woman's decrepit condition.
And what I remember most about the story was the doctor's impression when he first met his client, seeing her as a withered old hag on death's door, thus explaining her desperation and desire to try unproven therapies.

“...But I’ve never heard of a health-care system with a mean service
time of less than a minute. What you have is incredibly good.” “It may
be. It’s the best that money can buy. But it’s not good enough.” “I
don’t see how you could get a better one.” “You can build me one.”
Greenwood’s withered lips offered a faint smile. “Ah, you don’t think
you can, eh? But listen to me.” She paused for a long, shallow breath.
“Give me five minutes of your time.” “You bought four hours of it.” “I
want to buy more than that. Hear me out.” She touched one of the
controls on her wheelchair, and the back moved to a deeper reclining
angle. “One nice thing about having a bit of money, people come to
you, instead of you having to go to them. Now, you might think that
must be to my advantage, but funnily enough, it’s not so. Not always.
One month ago, the director of your hospital called, to tell me that
the new wing I’d financed was going to be opened, and would I like to
be there for the ceremony. I hadn’t left this building for over a
year, because my doctors were advising against it. But I decided I was
going. I didn’t know why. I think my subconscious did. All my life
I’ve played hunches. I said I was going, and I told Ronson — my head
doctor — to shut up. If I dropped dead while I was out, that would be
my own dumb fault. So they wheeled me out, and they propped me up in
the limo, and took me down to Georgetown.” She sighed, the weak,
chesty sigh of a sixty-year smoker. “I saw the new wing, but I saw
more than that. I saw the equipment in the wing. And I saw OPEC — ^the
Online Patient Experimental Clinic. Your own lab. Telemetry feeds,
direct from patient to computer. Feedback within ten milliseconds.”

